# Nonseparable Hilbert spaces as quotients of spaces of bounded functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is the following result true: the Hilbert space $\ell^{2}\left(2^{\Gamma}\right)$ is a quotient of $\ell^{\infty}\left(\Gamma\right)$ for any
uncountable $\Gamma$ ? [I think it is, but cannot remember where I saw it, long time ago.] I would be very grateful for any (freely available, if possible) reference (Pelczynski ? Rosenthal ?).

Comment: @Ady:  I made a major addition to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know who first observed this (maybe Archimedes?) but it is true because $C(\{0,1 \}^\Gamma)$ is a quotient of $\ell_1^\Gamma$ and hence $\ell_1(2^\Gamma)$ embeds into $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$.

@Ady

Here is a more serious answer to your question.  Take a quotient map $Q$ from $\ell_1(2^\Gamma)$ onto $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ and extend to a norm one mapping $T$ from $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ into some injective space $Z$ that contains $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ (you cannot extend $Q$ to an operator from  $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ into  $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ because, e.g., $C([0,1]$ is not a quotient of $\ell_\infty$).  Use partitions of unity to get a net $(P_a)$ of norm one finite rank projections on $Z$ taking values in $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ and whose restrictions to $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ converge strongly to the identity.  A weak$^*$ cluster point of $(P_a^* T^*)$ gives an isometric embedding of the dual of $C([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$ (which contains $L_1([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$) into the dual of $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$.  Thus if $Y^*$ is any reflexive subspace of  $L_1([0,1]^{2^\Gamma})$, such as $\ell_2(2^\Gamma)$, then $Y$ is isometric to a quotient of $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$.

Comment: [deleted earlier comment as I had misread Bill's answer]

Comment: @Bill Johnson Could you be more specific, please ? Since the Hilbert space is not injective. Some extension result ?

Comment: I'll give you a hint, Ady.  Use a famous theorem of the first Fields Medalist who worked in Banach space theory. 

Comment: Maybe the second one, historically speaking. And he has many famous theorems. Still, I think that this is a result of Pelczynski or Rosenthal. Perhaps involving the Bohr compactification.

Comment: @Bill Johnson Grothendieck-Maurey Theorem ?

Comment: To my way of thinking, Laurent Schwartz worked in functional analysis but not Banach space theory, at least before he was awarded the medal. But let's not quibble...

The operator extends because it is 2-summing, so you need only the little G theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, Professor Johnson. I was thinking before at Thms. 8 and 9 in 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC224678/pdf/pnas00116-0059.pdf . And,
a bit paradoxically, I found the G-M Thm. in 
http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.bams/1183547996 :-).
Thank you very much again.

Comment: That first link doesn't work for me. 

Notice that the argument I gave shows only that $\ell_2(2^\Gamma)$  is isomorphic to a quotient of  $\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$. But if $\ell_2(A)$ embeds isomorphically into $L_1(\mu)$, must it embed isometrically? Maybe you can prove this using Maharam's theorem...